# Gitlab Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name is already in use by container

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Gitlab CI in my development for continuous integration. I have my gitlab-runner runnig on a ubuntu instance.

I have one application, where i use MongoDB v3.6. I have to do a database integration test in the test stage of my CI/CD.

```
prepare:
    image: node:11.10.1-alpine
    stage: setup
    script:
    - npm install --quiet node-gyp
    - npm install --quiet
    - npm install -g yarn
    - chmod a+rwx  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn*
    - chmod a+rwx  /usr/local/bin/yarn*
    - yarn install
    - cd client
    - yarn install
    - cd ../
    - cd admin
    - yarn install
    cache:
        key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        paths:
        - node_modules/
        - client/node_modules/
        - admin/node_modules/
        policy: push

app_testing:
    image: node:11.10.1-alpine
    services:
    - name: mongo:3.6
    stage: test
    cache:
        key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        paths:
        - node_modules/
        - client/node_modules/
        - admin/node_modules/
    script:
    - yarn run test
    - cd client
    - yarn run test
    - cd ../
    - cd admin
    - yarn run test
```

For every alternate pipeline, i am getting the below **error in the app_testing( test ) stage**.

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/runner-e7ce6426-project-11081252-concurrent-0-mongo-0" is already in use by container "0964b061b56d8995966f577e7354852130915228bac1a7513a773bbb82aeefaf". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

Below is the full log of the specific job which is failing

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.8.0 (079aad9e)
  on SharedRunner-XYZGroup e7ce6426
Using Docker executor with image node:11.10.1-alpine ...
Starting service mongo:3.6 ...
Pulling docker image mongo:3.6 ...
Using docker image sha256:57c2f7e051086c7618c26a2998afb689214b4213edd578f82fe4b2b1d19ee7c0 for mongo:3.6 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image node:11.10.1-alpine ...
Starting service mongo:3.6 ...
Pulling docker image mongo:3.6 ...
Using docker image sha256:57c2f7e051086c7618c26a2998afb689214b4213edd578f82fe4b2b1d19ee7c0 for mongo:3.6 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/runner-e7ce6426-project-11081252-concurrent-0-mongo-0" is already in use by container "0964b061b56d8995966f577e7354852130915228bac1a7513a773bbb82aeefaf". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image node:11.10.1-alpine ...
Starting service mongo:3.6 ...
Pulling docker image mongo:3.6 ...
Using docker image sha256:57c2f7e051086c7618c26a2998afb689214b4213edd578f82fe4b2b1d19ee7c0 for mongo:3.6 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/runner-e7ce6426-project-11081252-concurrent-0-mongo-0" is already in use by container "0964b061b56d8995966f577e7354852130915228bac1a7513a773bbb82aeefaf". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/runner-e7ce6426-project-11081252-concurrent-0-mongo-0" is already in use by container "0964b061b56d8995966f577e7354852130915228bac1a7513a773bbb82aeefaf". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

I tried disabling secondary caches, it didn't work for me.

Now i don't know how to fix this issue. As a workaround, i have to trigger a new pipeline every time it fails, which of course no one likes, as the ultimate goal for anyone to automate things is to focus on most important things.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4327. GitLab is re-using the same service container name. This approach fails if the previous container wasn't deleted in time.

If you read through the (long list of) comments you may discover some workarounds of which are among others:

- limit concurrency to 1
- increase your Runner's machine's IOPS (e.g. switch from HDD to SSD)

As we were facing the same issue with the Docker executor, we currently kind of worked around it by using the Docker+Machine executor. Although you can't really be sure to avoid that error, my experience is that jobs are running more reliably since then. The tradeoff, however, is that for each job a VM is provisioned that wants to be paid.

Comment: Thank you Marcel. I wasted almost a day on trying to fix this using disable_cache in runners.docker config of gitlab-runner. I even tried modifying my code, thinking it could be some sort of code issue.

Right now my concurrency limit to 1
I am using SSD, but not sure how fast an SSD should be. I am using Azure cloud.
I still have the issue.

Comment: Funnily enough, we also use Azure. I've updated my answer and added some info about our current Docker+Machine executor "workaround".

Comment: Thanks for updating on the workaround. My company wouldn't let me pay any extra.

I have a simple workaround though, just hit "Retry Job" once it fails. This will fix my issue, but it's like i have to do every time i commit my code.